# Convert datetime to seconds in python using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

How do you convert a timestamp in this format: 30/05/2022 13:05:48.360 to seconds?

This is the code I have so far:

```
    def getDataset(self,csvfilename):
        
        dataset={}
        
        """remove NaN and set to 0"""
        df = pd.read_csv(csvfilename, encoding='utf-8').fillna(0)
        
        """name of headers in column"""
        list_columns = df.columns.values.tolist() 
        
        """set time format"""
        time_format = '%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f'
                

        for col in list_columns:
            dataset[col] = df[col].iloc[0:].values
            try:
                dataset[col] = [datetime.strptime(i, time_format) for i in df[col].iloc[0:].values]
            except Exception as e:
                pass
                print(e)
             
        return dataset,list_columns
```

I have tried changing `dataset[col] = [datetime.strptime(i, time_format) for i in df[col].iloc[0:].values]` to `dataset['Timestamp'] = df.loc[:,'Timestamp].datetime.total_seconds()`but it is not working. I keep getting a "'Series' object has no attribute 'datetime'" error...Timestamp is the column that the datetime format is located in my data. The rest of the columns do not have to be converted. How can I change datetime to seconds in a specific column?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fastest way I know is to cast the datetime-values to `int64` which gives you the time in `ns`. And then divide by `10**9`.

Example df:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(["28/05/2022 13:05:48.360", "29/05/2022 13:05:48.360", "30/05/2022 13:05:48.360"], columns=["dates"])
df.dates = pd.to_datetime(df.dates, format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Then use:

```
df.dates.astype('int64') // 10**9
```

to get

```
0    1653743148
1    1653829548
2    1653915948
Name: dates, dtype: int64
```

Comment: My output changes to "2022-05-30 13:05:48.360" and then it says dtype=datetime64[ns]. How can I get it to output what you received?

Comment: I typed:                                                                                             
       for col in list_columns:
            dataset[col] = df[col].iloc[0:].values

        dataset['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(dataset['Timestamp'])
        
        dataset['Timestamp'].astype('int64') // 10**9

Comment: dataset['Timestamp'] = dataset['Timestamp'].astype('int64') // 10**9

Comment: If this does not work right away, maybe you could add the first n rows of your dataset using `dataset.head(n).to_dict()`so I can recreate your data

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for datetime.datetime.timestamp()

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp